# Exiftool create several JSon files from just one directory

Tags: java, exiftool

Does anybody know how I could get several JSon files by executing `exiftool` just once? 
I could generate one JSon file from my directory, with all metadata from files inside this folder, but I want to get one for each file. I want also to put all the files generated in a specific folder. I also tried to make a loop inside my folder, and call exiftool once for each file, but this is not right solution, because I have one process for each file.

I have checked the whole [exiftool documentation](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html#copying_examples), but wasn't able to find the correct combination of parameters.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect these separated JSon files, I used this command:

```
exiftool -a -u -g1 -j -k -r -w OUTDIR/%f.json INPUTDIR
```

Not `-o` option, because it is the output directory when *writing* the image.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the purpose of the `exiftool -w` option:

```
exiftool -w json ...
```

This will generate `.json` files, one for each input file.